# Angular 6 gives error"TypeError: Cannot read property" when calling a property from another component while using modal

Tags: angular, modalpopup, mdbootstrap

I am new to angular so i apologize if i make silly mistakes when i try to call current value of component A from component B. it gives error. i am trying to call these value when a popup modal form is active. on click of open popup i tried to call a function  "editUserData()" but it gives error.

component A

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { userRegistrationData } from 
'src/app/models/registrationUser.models';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { EditUserDetailComponent } from '../editUser/edit-user-detail/edit- 
user-detail.component';
@Component({
selector: 'app-registration-form',
templateUrl: './registration-form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./registration-form.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationFormComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient ) { }


public currentValue: string;


editUserData(value:any): void
{
  this.currentValue = value;
}

}
```

> Component B

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ViewChildren, AfterViewInit, 
ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Injectable, AfterViewChecked, 
AfterContentInit, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import {ModalDirective} from 'mdbootstrap';
import { userRegistrationData } from 
'src/app/models/registrationUser.models';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RegistrationFormComponent } from '../../registration- 
form/registration-form.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-edit-user-detail',
templateUrl: './edit-user-detail.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit-user-detail.component.css']
})

export class EditUserDetailComponent implements OnInit , AfterViewInit {
 public editThisDetail: userRegistrationData;
value : string;
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, ){}

@ViewChild('RegistrationFormComponent') registrationFormComponent: 
RegistrationFormComponent;


 @ContentChild(RegistrationFormComponent)
public registraionComponent :  RegistrationFormComponent;



  pushData()
  {
    console.log("asif");
    console.log("asif",this.registraionComponent.currentValue);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.pushData();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  }
```

**error In code : RegistrationFormComponent.html:81 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentValue' of undefined
    at EditUserDetailComponent.push../src/app/createUser/editUser/edit-user-detail/edit-user-detail.component.ts.EditUserDetailComponent.pushData (edit-user-detail.component.ts:50)
    at EditUserDetailComponent.push../src/app/createUser/editUser/edit-user-detail/edit-user-detail.component.ts.EditUserDetailComponent.ngAfterViewInit**

Comment: Since your error is in the HTML, it would be well advised to give us the related HTML code ...

Comment: Just do `whatever?.currentValue` instead of `whatever.currentValue` in your template.

Answer (score 0):

In your case is `EditUserDetailComponent` child and `RegistrationFormComponent` is parent, you can access through DI as following -

#### EditUserDetailComponent

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, 
     @Inject(forwardRef(() => RegistrationFormComponent)) private registraionComponent:RegistrationFormComponent){

}
```

#### Remove following code

```
@ViewChild('RegistrationFormComponent') registrationFormComponent: 
RegistrationFormComponent;


 @ContentChild(RegistrationFormComponent)
public registraionComponent :  RegistrationFormComponent;
```

Comment: after removing these two lines and tried to access through `viewChild` i still get this error: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentValue' of undefined
    at EditUserDetailComponent.push**

Comment: here is the code at github: [link](https://github.com/asif212/userRegistration)
please check this.

Comment: path: userRegistration/src/app/createUser/editUser/edit-user-detail/edit-user-detail.component.html

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: sorry but still can't resolve this issue. can you please help me on private chat @ asifmoin786@gmail.com

Comment: Create stackblitz demo so that it can be fixed and quicker.